# Continuous white noise

Tags: white-noise

I have been reading about topics that include statistics, and slowly start to get a grasp. However sometimes it seems to me that I dont get the simplest concepts.

White noise seems to have several definitions, from what i found out, but the most important is the constant amplitude in the frequency domain.
It can be specifially gaussian distributed or not- which is not what i want to discuss.

The fact, that gives to trouble is whether the outcome of a point depends on the previous or not. If it doesnt(which makes sense to me) how would continuous-time white noise look like? 
Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_noise#Continuous-time_white_noise) mentions it but I dont really understand it. Sadly there is no entry in my mothertongue either.

Since this is my first question I would appreciate constructive feedback on possible improvements/standards for posts I should respect.

Comment: Are you asking how a time series consisting only of white noise looks like?

Comment: Not a series but continuous, in time domain! I think i have seen it only in discrete steps with lines connected inbetween. And maybe generally the idea of continuous white noise? Is the concept even important?

Comment: So instead of there being fixed intervals between data points the intervals are also random? You can expect the same shape to appear as in the fixed interval case.

Comment: No with continuous I mean no(infinitesimaly small) interval in between 2 data points. But maybe this is a retarded question and not useful for getting an idea about noise.